# include in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying Ruby on Rails integration with the Authorize.Net API from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-ruby/blob/master/AcceptSuite/create-an-accept-payment-transaction.rb.
When I try to run this ruby code in a method of a custom controller

```
   class PaymentController < ApplicationController

     def create_an_accept_payment_transaction
         include AuthorizeNet::API
         config = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../credentials.yml")

         transaction = Transaction.new(config['api_login_id'], config['api_transaction_key'], :gateway => :sandbox)

         request = CreateTransactionRequest.new

        ...............
        if response.messages.resultCode == MessageTypeEnum::Ok
        ................
     end
   end
```

I was getting the following errors

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `include' for #<PaymentController:0x000000000296d118>)
```

and

```
 NameError (uninitialized constant PaymentController::MessageTypeEnum
 Did you mean?  MessagePack):
```

But the same ruby code is working without any issue in a method in an ActiveRecord model.**WHY ?**

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

def self.payment_transaction(token, amount)
      require 'yaml'
      require 'authorizenet' 
      require 'securerandom'
      include AuthorizeNet::API
      config = YAML.load_file(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../credentials.yml")
      transaction = Transaction.new(config['api_login_id'], config['api_transaction_key'], :gateway => :sandbox)
     request = CreateTransactionRequest.new
      request.transactionRequest = TransactionRequestType.new()
    ..................
 end
 end
```

I could also run this ruby code without any issues with

```
    $ ruby create-an-accept-payment-transaction.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

The `payment_transaction` is a class method, whereas `create_an_accept_payment_transaction` is an instance method. The `include AuthorizeNet::API` call works in the class not in the instance.

Try this instead:

```rb
require 'authorizenet' 
class PaymentController < ApplicationController  
  include AuthorizeNet::API
end
```